# A bot where you can answer dms in the console log or a discord channel

Tags: discord, readline, discord.js

I searched it up and got a code with readline where it looks like this:

```
const Disc = require('discord.js');
const client = new Disc.Client();
const token = 'token' 
const readline = require('readline');

client.login(token);

client.on('message', function(message){
    if(message.channel.type === 'dm'){
        console.log("[" + message.author.username + "]: " + message.content) 


        const rl = readline.createInterface({
            input: process.stdin,
            output: process.stdout
        });

        rl.question('REPLY TO ' + message.author.username + ': ', (answer) => {
            message.author.send(`${answer}`);
            rl.close();
        });
     }
 });
```

But it doesn't work helpp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? Why exactly is it not working for you; what is the error?

Comment: It doesn't say it just doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a topic I just did recently actually, so I'll walk you through it and give you some code to go along with it.

First, I would like to say when your making a post, include a clear question. From what it sounds like, your asking for a bot that logs dms to the console, or responds to them. I will just answer both questions.

The easiest way to check for a DM is to see if the message channel type is DM. Check [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel) for more info on the channel class. You can check if a channel is a certain type by doing this:

```js
if (message.channel.type === 'dm'){ } // change dm to the type you want
```

This will have to go in your on message function, so right now, if you're following along, the code would look like this:

```js
bot.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm'){ }
});
```

From there it's simply adding code to the inside of the if statement. You will always want a return statement inside of it just incase nothing happens, so it doesn't try to do anything in the channels.

For what you want, this will log the DM to the console and reply to it, if it is equal to a certain message.

```js
bot.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm'){ 
        console.log(message.content);
        if(message.content === "something"){
            return await message.channel.send("Hi!");
        }
        return;
    }
});
```

This should do what you want, if you have any questions, comment it on here and I'll respond as soon as possible :)

edit:

```js
bot.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm'){ 
        console.log(`${message.author.username} says: ${message.content}`);
        const rl = readline.createInterface({
            input: process.stdin,
            output: process.stdout
        });

        rl.question(`REPLY TO ${message.author.username}: `, (answer) => {
            message.author.send(`${answer}`);
            rl.close();
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: What if I like want to be able to answer, send a dm from the bot of own choice from the console log and not just make it answer somethings?

Comment: Also there was a fail in yours you have to remove the await from `return await message.channel.send("Hi!");`

Comment: You shouldn't need to remove the await, it's in an async function. I'm not sure what you mean by "answer, send a dm from the bot of own choice from the console log and not just make it answer somethings?" could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Like being able to send an answer from the console log

Comment: I made an edit to my post, try that and tell me if it works, its the code under "edit."

Comment: It works thanks a lot ^^ you don't know anything about like making bot log server messages unto folders by chance do you? Could be nice.

Comment: You're welcome, I don't know how to log it into files, but I know how to log it into a text channel on discord. If you would want that, would you want it to log every message?